# Default attribute value for all product in magento 

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I want to set a default value of an attribute for all product.

Comment: Provide a piece of code that you have tried already.!

Comment: actually i have not tried any code but, but i need to do it. i am trying.

Comment: ya...you are right....but i did not get the correct answer..

help me if you can....

Comment: If you don't get the correct answer, edit your original question.  Don't create a new question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, so either post some code, ask a coding-related question or ask the question on webmasters.stackexchange

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem before,when i added 11096 product(downloadable products) in my store then client told me to add new attributes in product so i create 1 attribute (Type is Yes/No) and set to attribute set.
Now my problem is how can i edit all product and set that attribute yes or not.if i not set then value is null so i wrote few line code.

Please check this code may be it'll helpful to you.

```
$ProductId = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE)
    ->getAllIds();
//Now create an array of attribute_code => values

$attributeData = array("my_attribute_code" =>"my_attribute_value");

//Set the store to affect. I used admin to change all default values

$storeId = 0; 

//Now Update the attribute for the given products.

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes($ProductId, $attributeData, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated here:- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields

> **Default Value:** You can enter a value that will automatically populate
>   for new products.

So, I think it only applies for New products that you create after you create that attribute. Hence, the attribute's default value setting might not be applied to those products which were created before creating the attribute.

I had the similar issue and to solve it, I wrote the following code in the file where I want to display the attribute's default value:-

```
$attributeCode = 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE';
$attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
            ->setCodeFilter($attributeCode)
            ->getFirstItem();
echo $attribute->getDefaultValue();
```

Comment: Be careful! That `entity_attribute_collection` contains attributes for other entities besides products (customers, categories, etc...). Make sure you filter by entity type too: `$collection->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can also solve the problem by doing a massupdate for all products. Go to the Manage Products paga and Select All followed by Update attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Attribute management

Admin panel - Catalog - Attributes - Manage Attributes

Select attribute - Properties - Attribute Properties - Default value

[image]

Comment: can you tell me how it is possible with attribute management.

Comment: my attribute is dropdown. i cant seeany default value option in attribute properties.
sorry....but thanks for trying to help me...if there is another process then please tell

Comment: For dropdown you can use Is Default option on Manage Label/Options tab

Comment: actually i have done that but that is working for the products i have adding after that, but i want that for existing products. Help me please

Comment: try to remove attribute from consistent attribute set, save and add it again

Comment: i tried but not working. still not selected in existing products