# default attribute value for all existing product in magento product in magento

Tags: magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [default attribute value for all product in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906497/default-attribute-value-for-all-product-in-magento)

hi....everybody....

i have a dropdown attribute in my nmagento admin panel. i want a default value for all products. i have set is default option in manage attribute-->options tab,but that is working for only new products. i want to set default attribute value for all existing products.

is there anybody to help me?????????