# sql to insert default attribute values to all products in magento

Tags: magento, insert, entity-attribute-value

I installed an extension that adds an attribute which you can turn on per product when you edit or add a new product... but I need to add it to all existing products.

a) sql?

b) point me to a class somewhere that does this for a Magento collection?

Similar question, but I need to do it in sql or module: [Default attribute value for all product in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906497/default-attribute-value-for-all-product-in-magento)

Comment: 1.) You say you have an extension that allows you to do this. Why not attempt to extend the code thats already there. if its working, modify it, to work as a mass action.

Comment: 2.) create a loop that iterates through all products, in a separate action, passing the necessary fields to that same function that works for a single product. i imagine there would be a possibility to do this. if you could paste me the code we can go through it.

Comment: Without attempting to give you an answer in raw sql (since we are using an OO framework i would assume you should rather use objects and their methods to interact with the database).

Comment: Yes to answer (2)... that is ideal. I was hoping that someone (heh) could point me to a snippet of magento code that does just that. There are about 10 billion undocumented objects in Magento (rough estimate), and I am not a Magento expert by any means. I will be back on this on Thursday and will see if I can github.gist the code that I would like to modify... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> adds an attribute which you can turn on per product

Been here before.

Does it show up in product maintenance now that the module is installed? If so, then it will show up in an export profile. Make an export for skuid, store, type and the new attribute and export to a CSV file. Make sure use Magento column headings is set to yes. Set the new attribute to what you need it to be in the CSV file for what product you need set and import it using the Import All Products profile.

Freshly installed module attributes will default to blank until something edited on the page the attribute shows on is saved. Use the profile import to set them all to yes or 1 if it's a yes/no enable type field to enable across the board. You will have to check the export to see if they're using yes/no in the database or boolean 1/0.

If this attribute is a dropdown item, you will need to create all the selection items in Attribute Maintenance and make sure the value in the upload file matches exactly the selection in attribute maintenance so the upload will work.

As an added note, if this attribute is only created on simple items, filter your export to only include simple items for inclusion in the import file.

It sounds like one of those one-time deals where expending a lot of effort on throwaway code violates the KISS method when a simple import will fix it and you're done with the operation for good.

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea which I had not realized would work. I have used the "magmi" http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi module in the past to do major imports but have never tried to update product attributes or options using the exp/imp method. I might do this, but, honestly I need to hone my Magento coding skills as well.

Comment: Creating code for the sake of learning isn't a waste of time. I'll agree on that. The question's still open for answering then.